# How can I decode a rfc2047 encoded string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mime

I have a service which returns e.g. jpg file. Name of it is in Content-Disposition header, but the filename is encoded in rfc2047 standard, so I have:

```
filename="=?UTF-8?Q?=C4=99=C5=9B.jpg?=" => decoded to = ęś.jpg
```

I found that there is in Java `MimeUtility.decodeText` which works nice, but I need to decode this text on client site using Angular 8. I tried to decode this text on server-site using Java and pass it to client-site and then decode it using `decodeURIComponent(escape(filename))`, but it doesn't work.

Is there any equivalent of function or maybe npm dependency to decode it in Angular 8?

Answer (score 1):

If you can perform the decoding on server side, then do that and then encode it using something that JS can decode natively.

For example, you could send URL-encoded (percent encoded) string, which would be `%C4%99%C5%9B.jpg` in your example, and decode it using `decodeURIComponent()` (note that you should not add the `escape` call as in your question).

Base64 won't work because the JS built-in method (`atob`) will need extra work to decode these characters (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa#unicode_strings)

Or if you are looking for npm module, here is one that supports parsing the value directly: https://www.npmjs.com/package/content-disposition

Comment: In meanwhile I create some workaround. First of all I decode on server-site this name using `MimeUtility.decodeText`, than next I encode it using `URLEncoder.encode(decodeText, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())`. On client-site I just decode this text using `decodeURIComponent`. 
I did this before reading your answer. What can I see I did what you suggest on the first paragraph. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this topic when my AWS SES subject line contains some non standard characters. I found this repo but it's a NodeJS project. https://github.com/One-com/rfc2047. I also made static site https://ldu2.github.io/rfc2047/ for live conversion. Just in case someone wants my source code. https://github.com/ldu2/rfc2047